# How to do an efficient partial string match in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, lookup

I have a dataframe of around 50k strings containing some variations of city names like these.

| city | variation |
| --- | --- |
| new delhi | new dilli |
| new delhi | delhi |
| new delhi | dilli |
| new delhi | nayi dilli |
| bengaluru | bangalore |
| bengaluru | blr |
| bengaluru | bengalur |
| mysore | mysuru |
| mysore | mysur |
| mysore | mysore |
| mysore | mysor |

I have an inverted index (2 million variations) created from similar, but noisy variations from a larger dataset where variations are present. I want to calculate how many times each of these variations in the above table appears at least partially in the larger dataset.

Table to lookup in:

| city_variations | indices | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| new dilli #num | [2,3,51,44,33] | 5 |
| new dilliplace | [231,3,11,44] | 4 |
| new york | [1231,2211] | 2 |
| #num new dilli##num | [211,4223,532] | 3 |

I am expecting my results to contain:
 `new dilli -> new dilli #num, new dilliplace and #num new dilli##num`

My code is also added below, this works, but takes forever! Can someone suggest me ways to optimize it?

```py
def if_contains(pattern,df,col,sum_col):
    return df[df[col].str.contains(pattern)][sum_col].sum()

inputs["count_of_vns_with_pattern"] = inputs.apply(
    lambda x: if_contains(
        x["variation"], inv_index, "city_variations", "No.of times present in inv index"
    ),
    axis=1,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to increase speed could be to step outside Pandas and use a dictionary comprehension for counting.

With the toy dataframes you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "city": [
            "new delhi",
            "new delhi",
            "new delhi",
            "new delhi",
            "bengaluru",
            "bengaluru",
            "bengaluru",
            "mysore",
            "mysore",
            "mysore",
            "mysore",
        ],
        "variation": [
            "new dilli",
            "delhi",
            "dilli",
            "nayi dilli",
            "bangalore",
            "blr",
            "bengalur",
            "mysuru",
            "mysur",
            "mysore",
            "mysor",
        ],
    }
)

other_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "city_variations": [
            "new dilli #num",
            "new dilliplace",
            "new york",
            "#num new dilli##num",
        ],
        "indices": ["[2,3,51,44,33]", "[231,3,11,44]", "[1231,2211]", "[211,4223,532]"],
        "count": [5, 4, 2, 3],
    }
)
```

Here is how your code performs on my machine:

```py
other_df["count"] = 1
df["count_with_pandas"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: if_contains(x["variation"], other_df, "city_variations", "count"), axis=1
)

# 4.04 ms ± 160 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Now, with Python:

```py
counts = {
    variation: sum(
        True if variation in city_variation else False
        for city_variation in other_df["city_variations"]
    )
    for variation in df["variation"]
}

df = (
    pd.concat([df.set_index("variation"), pd.Series(counts)], axis=1)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"index": "variation", 0: "count_with_python"})
)

# 976 µs ± 34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Which is 4x faster approximately in average for the same output:

```py
print(df)
```

[image]

It would be interesting to see if you get the same speed improvement with your real data.